# C++ vector and array

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a HackerRank question named "Array Manipulation"[The link of the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem?isFullScreen=false).
I wrote this code below. It works fine. However, when I use an array instead of vector I got segmentation fault at case 7-13. Why did it happen?

```
long arrayManipulation(int n, vector<vector<int>> queries) {
    vector<long> arr(n);
    long sum=0, max=LONG_MIN;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<queries.size();i++){
        arr[queries[i][0]-1] += queries[i][2];
        if(queries[i][1]<n) arr[queries[i][1]] -= queries[i][2];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum += arr[i];
        if(sum>max) max=sum;
    }
    return max; }
```

```
long arrayManipulation(int n, vector<vector<int>> queries) {
    long arr[n];
    long sum=0, max=LONG_MIN;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<queries.size();i++){
        arr[queries[i][0]-1]+=queries[i][2];
        if(queries[i][1]<n) arr[queries[i][1]]-=queries[i][2];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum+=arr[i];
        if(sum>max) max=sum;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: You probably go out of bounds, which leads to *undefined behavior*, which unfortunately sometimes might seem to work. How is this function called? What is the contents of `queries`?

Comment: "queries[i][0]-1" looks suspicious to result in "-1" at some point and thus access a position of "arr" that cannot exist. Best would be if you run the vector variant in an IDE with debugger activated so you get an error when the vector is accessed out of bounds.

Comment: Apart from the possibility of going out of array bounds ...  `long arr[n]` where `n` is a variable (or function argument) is a VLA (variable length array) which is not valid C++. Some compilers support VLAs as a non-standard extension. Those that do support VLAs typically use process stack space, which is subject to a fairly small quota under most unix environments so the possible size of such an array is therefore significantly smaller than is possible with a `std::vector`, which uses dynamic memory allocation. A fairly common symptom of exceeding available stack space is a segmentation fault

Comment: `long arr[n];` -- I wish that these coding sites such as HackerRank would turn on the correct compiler options to make this illegal, or at least give that option to do so.  This is not legal C++.  As to using `std::vector`, use the `at()` function instead of `[ ]` to access the elements in the vector.  If you now get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown, then indeed you are going out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Variable length arrays have a limit of available stack limit, if it surpasses the limit SegV (by stack overflow) can occur.

The same can happen for fixed length array if size is large enough.

Try with this to see the issue:

```
long arr[10000000];  // should fail for same reason in HackerRank
```

Comment: Also important to note that VLAs are not standard C++ (they're a compiler extension)